# How to merge staging branch with live

Tags: git, continuous-integration, teamcity

Let's say I'm happy with my staging deployment and I want to propagate it to live, I'm guessing that the next step is to merge the staging branch with live's. The build server checks out the live branch, builds and deploys. Except, what if the merge has some unexpected results?

How do I make sure that the final merge results in a successful deployment before writing over the live files?

Comment: You can do this by separating build and deployment. First build the live branch and then deploy, depending on the build status. I assume, 'unexpecting results' means, that the build would fail due to compiler errors for example!?

Comment: Some error resulting from the merge not resulting in an exact copy of the staging branch. This could be a missing asset, not necessarily something that would cause a compiler error. That's my point... the build status may miss something that one would only spot when using the site. That's possible isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to worry about errors resulting from merging, if you only merge your staging-branch into your live-branch and never commit any changes to the live-branch. See:

```
staging  A---B---C---E---F---G---H---J---K---L---M
                  \               \               \
live               D---------------I---------------N
```

This way there is no possibility for a merge conflict, because only the stating-branch changes over time.

Comment: Which begs the question: why should there even be a `live` branch to start with? The live deployments become nothing else than deployments of selected tags/labels from the `staging` branch...

Comment: @DanCornilescu You might not like your staging branch.